# External DVD createProcess returns 998

Tags: c, windows, winapi, copy

I am using copy, it works fine with the drive `C:` but i have a DVD i want to use this with and it returns err code `998` when i try to copy from the DVD.

What could be the reason? How do know what is the exact issue and how to solve this ?

```
  STARTUPINFO STARTinfP777;
  PROCESS_INFORMATION procInf7777;
  STARTinfP777.cb = sizeof(STARTinfP777);
  char allCmd[MAX_PATH] = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /c copy /y \"E:\\\" \"C:\\Path\"; // = drive letter; copy working fine
  printf("%s\n", allCmd);

  DWORD safsdkasf = 0;
  if(CreateProcess(WndCmpath, allCmd, NULL, NULL, FALSE, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &STARTinfP777, &procInf7777) == 0){

    printf("err %d\n", GetLastError());
    MessageBox(0, "Hata", "Dikkat!", MB_OK);
    exit(0);
  }
  WaitForSingleObject( procInf7777.hProcess, INFINITE );
  CloseHandle( procInf7777.hProcess );
  CloseHandle( procInf7777.hThread );
```

Comment: I'm curious to know why you use cmd to perform an action for which there exists an API

Comment: @DavidHeffernan which one is that ?

Comment: `STARTinfP777` wrong intialized (all fields undefied, except first) this anf give error. and you must copy files by self, instead create new process

Comment: @RbMm İ understand. How by self ? Which Ali? `CopyFile()` i also had problem with that function working with an external volume

Comment: SHFileOperationW for example, IFileOperation

Comment: Use [CopyFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-copyfile) to copy individual files, or [IFileOperation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifileoperation) to perform batch operations, with the ability to receive progress callbacks.

Comment: @RbMm thank you guys very much, can you link me to an example code what i am trying to accomplish, copying a folder and waiting the code, `IFileOperation` I need to finish a work quickly

Comment: @turmuka Refer to official sample [FileOperationSDKSampleReadMe](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/1d363ff4bd17d8e20415b92e2ee989d615cc0d91/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/shell/appplatform/fileoperations/FileOperationSDKSampleReadMe.txt) to see if it helps.